# SwiftUI: VStack/HStack/ZStack drag gesture not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I don't understand why the `DragGesture` doesn't work on VStack/HStack/ZStack. Consider the following simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .offset(y: offset.height)
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { val in
                self.offset = val.translation
            }
            .onEnded { val in
                self.offset = .zero
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I'd like the whole view to move up and down based on the `offset` var (changed by the drag gesture). But even if I write the `.gesture` modifier on the `VStack` and even if the `VStack` is full screen (thanks to the `.frame` modifier) the drag gesture won't work on the `VStack`. The gesture works only if I drag the "Hello world" text, but it's unresponsive if I drag outside the `Text` (but still inside the full screen `VStack`). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Actually, there's a SwiftUI feature meant to address just that issue with no need for a background.

Simply place `.contentShape(Rectangle())` just before your gesture modifier and it will respond to the whole enclosing rectangle. :)

Comment: Sorry, I found an error in my code - by mistake I called a custom struct DragGesture. Your suggestion works fine.

Comment: Note that the correct order is important: `.frame` needs to be called before `.contentShape`, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: amazing! such an easy fix

Answer (score 8):

Your container is transparent. Transparent thing does not handle events. So, add some background, like in demo below and all works.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .background(Color.white)
    .offset(y: offset.height)
    .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged { val in
            self.offset = val.translation
        }
        .onEnded { val in
            self.offset = .zero
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: "Your container is transparent. Transparent thing does not handle events" <= Thanks for your explanation.